# Build multiple reports with MS Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a program that fills 2 tables in SQL db, let's call them `tUser` and `tItems`.

`tItems` will contain 3 rows with a `piece` field, while `tUser` will contain 1 row with `totalNoOfPieces` field.

I have created a report in MS Report Builder 3.0 that shows whatever I need to, adding both those tables into my dataset, and one of the expressions there should show me `Piece 1 of 3` using the above fields, for example.

I'm currently using

```
=CStr(First(Fields!piece.Value, "DataSet1")) + " of " + CStr(First(Fields!totalNoOfPieces.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

How would I make it so RB generates `totalNoOfPieces` identical reports for me, where the only thing that changes is the `Piece x of y` part?

(I guess what I'm asking is how to do it so I get 3 reports that would represent

```
SELECT * FROM tItems
INNER JOIN tUser ON tItems.ID=tUser.ID
```

in those reports)

EDIT: I should specify, I know I can add a parameter and make available values be `SELECT piece FROM tItems` but I'm wondering how to auto generate report for all available values.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like the report file to be generated programatically, so there are separate RDL files, or that you would simply like the report itself to have multiple sections for the different data?

Comment: @Rich I mean I would like the report to be 3 identical sections with changed parameteres, can be in one same file. Just like I have a parameter for piece with values 1, 2 and 3, I would like to get report with 3 identical sections with that parameter changed.

Comment: Do you want three sections, or do you want just one section depending on which parameter a user puts in? If you want three sections, you run the query you have specified in your question. You can make a 'list' that varies by piece.Value, and within that a table for each piece.Value. If you want just one section, you need to make an SSRS parameter that asks the user for the piece.value, with available values from the different pieces.

Comment: @Rich Maybe this will clarify more: this is what I'm getting when I click Run: https://i.imgur.com/4uumd2g.jpg ; this is what I want to get when clicking Run: https://i.imgur.com/0dgKJYl.jpg - of course with the total number being dependant on how many pieces there actually are.

Comment: Look into using a List on your report (its another control, like a table or matrix) which lists the different pieces. Then in the List, include your current visual content. you don't need the user parameter any more.

Comment: I didn't know list can do that, I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: You can nest tables. Start with a column grouping on Piece to get your 3 sections and then nest whatever else you need within those. You can use the `RowNumber` function to get the 1 through 3 dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a version of your report that accepts two parameters say, @CurrentPiece and @TotalPieces plus any other parameters you currently require. You don't need to setup available values for the parameters as the user will never use this report directly.
- Test the report works manually by typing the parameter values in
- Create a new new report that accepts a parameter @TotalPieces, plus anything else you currently need to pass to the report in step 1.
- Create a dataset (say `dsLoop`) and set it's query definition to be the following:

dsLoop query:

```
   DECLARE @counter int = 1
   DECLARE @t TABLE (PieceNum int)

    WHILE @TotalPieces>= @counter
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @t SELECT @counter
            SET @counter = @counter +1
        END

    SELECT * FROM @t ORDER BY rownum`
```

- Add a Matrix to your report and set the dataset property to `dsLoop`
- Drag `PieceNum` from the dataset field list to the cell that says "Columns" (top right cell of matrix). This will create a column group grouped and sorted by `PieceNum`
- In the data cell, insert a subreport and set the subreport name to be the report you created in step 1
- Set the `@CurrentPiece` parameter of the subreport to be `PieceNum` (from the dataset) and set the @TotalPieces parameter to be loop report's @TotalPieces parameter.
- Set any additional parameters that your subreport requires.
- Set the column width to suit.

This should now give you a working report, you'll just need to tidy up/adjust anything not quite right.

If this is not clear let me know and I'll do a mock-up so you can see it in action.